# Check if video has loaded and pass it to parent component giving null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to see if a video has been loaded and can play in the child component (LandingComponent) and if it has, I want the parent Component (App) to set load is true and remove the spinner (SpinnerComponent) and display the entire webpage.

I am always getting a null on the 'video' in the parent component.
Even if I give a check if it is not null, the spinner keeps spinning infinitely.
On further check, I see that the landing component is also not getting rendered

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NavbarComponent from './Components/Navbar/navbar';
import AboutComponent from './Components/About/about';
import HealthComponent from './Components/Health/health';
import SpinnerComponent from './Components/Spinner/spinner';
import LandingComponent from './Components/Landing/landing';
import ContactUs from './Components/ContactUs/contactUs';
import Footer from './Components/Footer/footer';

function App() {
   const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => { 
    const video = document.getElementById('landing-video');
    console.log('video element:', video); // This is always null
    if (video) {
      video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => {
        setLoaded(true);
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {loaded ? (
        <>
          <NavbarComponent/>
          <LandingComponent onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}/>
          <AboutComponent/>
          <HealthComponent/>
          <ContactUs/>
          <Footer/>
        </>
      ) : (
        <SpinnerComponent fullscreen={true} />
      )}
      </>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

Landing.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'
import './styleLanding.css';
import AOS from 'aos';
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';
import sample from '../../videos/movie.mp4'

export const LandingComponent = () => {
   console.log('LandingComponent rendered'); // This is also null
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
  AOS.init();
  const video = videoRef.current;
  if (video) {
    video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => {
      video.play();
      setLoaded(true);
    });
  }
}, []);

    return (
        <div id="home" className="style-landing" >
          <div className="style-overlay"></div>
           <video ref={videoRef} id="landing-video" src={sample} type={'video/mp4'} preload={'auto'} className="style-video" autoPlay loop muted/>
          <div className="style-content">
            <h2 className="style-heading" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-offset="130">EXPERIENCE THE BEST</h2>
            <h1 className="style-sub-heading" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-offset="130">nutrition</h1>
          </div>
          </div>
    )
}

export default LandingComponent
```

Comment: keep that in mind that it's not a good idea to access the DOM the way you do it in vanilla JS because it's totally against the whole idea of React; instead of that you can make use of useRef hook.

Comment: I see
My main idea was to have the spinnercomponent until the video on the landingpage is not loaded, and once it is, I wanted to display all the components

Comment: So, you only render LandingPage when lodaded is true, so it is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There are just a few tweaks to be made.
First if I address the issue, in App.js,

```
{loaded ? (
        <>
          <NavbarComponent/>
          <LandingComponent onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}/>
          <AboutComponent/>
          <HealthComponent/>
          <ContactUs/>
          <Footer/>
        </>
      ) : (
        <SpinnerComponent fullscreen={true} />
      )}
```

LandingComponent is enclosed within condition.**If "loaded" state is true, only then the component and its html with will be added(inserted) to the DOM**.

**Since, "loaded" state is false initially, the video tag is not even inserted in the DOM.** So you cant capture the element by any means. You wont get it by document.getElementById ... So your spinner is shown infinitely.

**Workaround---**

Show your spinner as an overlay. With this, the video tag will be added into DOM and you can add listeners and perform actions.

For sample, try below code for understanding...

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import sampleVideo from "./../assets/sample-10s.mp4";

const Practice = () => {
  const vidRef = useRef();

  const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    vidRef.current.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
      vidRef.current.muted = true;
      vidRef.current.play();
      setShowLoader(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Hello World</div>

      <video
        ref={vidRef}
        src={sampleVideo}
        type="video/mp4"
        height={400}
        width={500}
      ></video>

      {showLoader && (
        <div
          id="spinnerdiv"
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            opacity: 0.3,
            backgroundColor: "black",
          }}
        ></div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Practice;
```

In your code, once video tag is added into DOM, you can access it in child component with your original code.

The main issue was your LandingComponent wasn't even present in DOM in the first place.